# "qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found" and "not symbolic link" error when reinstalling xcb

Tags: qt, ubuntu, rstudio, wsl-2, xcb

I'm attempting to install RStudio in WSL2. R itself works just fine, however when I install and try to run RStudio I get the following error:

> qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display
> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

I've seen that other people have solved this problem by:

[Installing libqt5x11extras5 and running the following command:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308128/failed-to-load-platform-plugin-xcb-while-launching-qt5-app-on-linux-without/902774#902774)

> `sudo ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/platforms/ /usr/bin/`

Attempting to reinstall libqt5x11extras5 and other xcb related libraries I get the following message at the end and rstudio still doesn't work:

> `/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libcuda.so.1 is not a symbolic link`

In the /wsl/lib/ folder there are what I believe are a few duplicate files of libcuda.so libcuda.so.1 and libcuda.so.1.1. This folder is read only and it seems like it's that way for a reason.

I'm assuming the solution involves making libcuda.so.1 a symbolic link but I'm not quite sure where I should be pointing it given wsl's slightly different file structure than regular ubuntu.

edit: for example I've tried

> `sudo ln -sf  /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libcuda.so.1 /usr/bin`

however it doesn't fix the issue with rstudio, and when I reinstall the xcb libraries I still get the same error about it not being a symbolic link.

edit 2: solved it! I needed to install windows 11 for the gui to work. I had read somewhere it would also work with the latest version of windows 10 but I guess not.